# Why jest mockImplementation doesn't work when its handler returns an array?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm doing the following, using array:

```js
jest.spyOn(DAO.prototype, 'executeQuery')
    .mockImplementation(function() {
        return [{"ss": 343}]; <-----
    });
```

However, when I'm running the test, everything hangs, the tests don't run at all.

This is the only line shown in the bash after executing `npm run test`

```sh
 RUNS  ./index.test.js
```

But, if I run using the following approach (without array), everything works well.

```js
jest.spyOn(DAO.prototype, 'executeQuery')
    .mockImplementation(function() {
        return {"ss": 343}; <-----
    });
```

What happens when we use array as a return value in `mockImplementation`?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: You sure this doesn't have something to do with the way the rest of your code uses `DAO.prototype.executeQuery()`? Executing queries is usually an async process so perhaps you should be using an `async` function implementation or at least returning a `Promise`